# Dynamic query string params in Wordpress Rest API

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I cant find any information in the Wordpress rest api documentation about how to pass in a dynamic string as part of a url, I know how to do an ID.

```
register_rest_route($this->namespace, '/' . $this->rest_base . '/(?P<type>)', [
            'args' => [
                'type' => [
                    'description' => __('Type of notification to generate', $this->pluginName),
                    'type' => 'string',
                    'enum' => ['product_question']
                ]
            ],
            [
                'methods' => \WP_REST_Server::CREATABLE,
                'callback' => [$this, 'create_item'],
                'permission_callback' => [$this, 'create_item_permissions_check'],
                'args' => $this->get_endpoint_args_for_item_schema(\WP_REST_Server::CREATABLE)
            ],
            'schema' => [$this, 'get_public_item_schema']
        ]);
```

The above is the code im using to try and register the route. The route should look something like this `/notifications/product_question` The last part of the url, would be the dynamic part, and would be one of an array of values